# How should I prepare a bed of Chrysanthemums for winter?

Tags: flowers, pruning, perennials, overwintering, winter-gardening

I would like to prepare a bed of *Chrysanthemums* for the winter. The plants have grown up to sizes of 1 to 1.5 meters, some of then have colapsed slightly because they evidently became to large. I've been told that the bed contains both perennial and other varieties.

What is the best way to prepare this bed for the winter? For instance, would cutting all stems back to, say, 5 cm be a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I leave about 6" on the plants, just so they're easier to find. You can cut them back further if you want. It can be done in fall, winter, or in spring before new growth starts. Also, large areas are easiest to cut with a gas powered hedge clipper. Otherwise, hand shears will work.

Cutting below the lowest stem branches is helpful later when you have to rake leaves/debris out.